# Measure distance between points of STL file using three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, stl-format

I am trying to get the user to click on two different points and get distance between them.

The clicks seems to be happening at random positions, so the calculation is getting to be wrong.

The calculation is correct when the the OBJ loader is used and we use an OBJ file, but if I use an STL file using the STL loader, it just shows up incorrect.

Codepen link: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NLXavX

JS Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/qooungyrgltucai/three.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/ddt89ncslm4o7ie/Detector.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/mrhumrr2bxwt9nt/OBJLoader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/n5sjyymajykna51/TGALoader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/y4r5bmq2037jacg/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/h18h48v52739df4/STLLoader.js"></script>
<script>
var container;
var camera, controls, scene, renderer, model;

init();
animate();

function init() {
    container = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(container);

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
    camera.position.z = 5;

    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);

    // scene
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040); //0x101030
    scene.add(ambient);

    var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
    directionalLight.position.set(1, 1, 1).normalize();
    scene.add(directionalLight);

    // Loading manager
    var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
    manager.onProgress = function (item, loaded, total) {
        console.log(item, loaded, total);
    };

    var onProgress = function (xhr) {
        if (xhr.lengthComputable) {
            var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
            console.log(Math.round(percentComplete, 2) + '% downloaded');
        }
    };

    var onError = function (xhr) {
        console.log('Error: ' + xhr);
    };

    // Model
    //model = new THREE.Object3D();
    //scene.add(model);

    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: 0xffffff,
        needsUpdate: true
    });

    window.model ='';



    // Added an if else here, STL code:

    var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
                loader.load( 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/t57h7xketafodui/5a9b75e521aaf-DI_PIPE_FBG_holder.stl', function ( geometry ) {

                    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xff5533, specular: 0x111111, shininess: 200 } );
                    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

                    mesh.position.set( 0, - 0.25, 0.6 );
                    mesh.rotation.set( 0, - Math.PI / 2, 0 );
                    mesh.scale.set( 0.05, 0.05, 0.05 );

                    mesh.castShadow = true;
                    mesh.receiveShadow = true;

                    scene.add( mesh );

                window.model = scene;

                } ); 



    // This OBJ Loader will load if user requests an OBJ file. 
        var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader(manager);
    var object = loader.load('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/pn3yw6w5962o5r8/BIGIPIGI.obj', function (Object) {

        Object.castShadow = true;
        Object.position.x = 0;
        Object.position.y = -1;
        Object.position.z = 0;

        Object.traverse(function (child) {
            if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                child.material = material;
            }
        });
        console.log(Object);
                window.model = Object;
        scene.add(Object);
    }, onProgress, onError);
        // Object

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    document.addEventListener('mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false);
    window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
}

function onWindowResize() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

// Measurement Code

var pointA = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 1, 0 );
var pointB = new THREE.Vector3();

var markerA = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.SphereGeometry( 0.1, 16, 16 ), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xFF5555, depthTest: false, depthWrite: false } ) );
var markerB = markerA.clone();
scene.add( markerA );
scene.add( markerB );

var line;

function getIntersections( event ) {
  var vector = new THREE.Vector2();

  vector.set(
    ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1,
    - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1 );

  var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
  raycaster.setFromCamera( vector, camera );    

  var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( window.model.children );

  return intersects;

}

function getLine( vectorA, vectorB ) {

  var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
  geometry.vertices.push( vectorA );
  geometry.vertices.push( vectorB );
  var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
    color: 0xFFFF00,
    depthWrite: false,
    depthTest: false
  });
  line = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );
  return line;

}

function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {

  var intersects = getIntersections( event );

  if( intersects.length > 0 ){

    if ( ! pointB.equals( pointA ) ) {
      pointB = intersects[ 0 ].point;
    } else {
      pointB = pointA;
    }
    pointA = intersects[ 0 ].point;
    markerA.position.copy( pointA );
    markerB.position.copy( pointB );

    var distance = pointA.distanceTo( pointB );

    if ( line instanceof THREE.Line ) {
      scene.remove( line );
    }
    if ( distance > 0 ) {
      console.log( "distance", distance );
      alert( "distance: "+distance );
            line = getLine( pointA, pointB );
      scene.add(line);
    }

  }

}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render();
}

function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}</script>
```

Comment: Just out of curiousity, what makes you think that the result is incorrect? What criteria of incorrectness? Any chance to see results of comparison between OBJ and STL models?

Comment: I have the codepen link above, it allows you to visit the page and see the STL file being loaded. The clicks don't go to the correct places. Try clicking on one corner and another click on another corner. It doesn't go diagonally, the points are not in the correct x/y position.

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use r71?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add in CSS section:

```
body{
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow! haha. It seemed to have worked. Another issue though. The Red dot circle seems to be going behind the object. Where can I change the z-index for it?

Comment: @Mohit If the answer solved your proplem, mark it as accepted. About your issue: remove `depthTest: false, depthWrite: false` from the material of `markerA`.